# Плавный выход и исчезновение блока корзины товаров

Tags: javascript

```js
(function($) {
  $(function() {
    $('.styler').styler();
  });
})(jQuery);

const page = document.querySelector('.page');
const modalBackdrop = document.querySelector('.modal-backdrop');
const orderForm = document.querySelector('.order-form');
const openModalBtns = document.querySelectorAll(
  '.button[data-action="open-modal"]',
);
const closeModalBtn = orderForm.querySelector(
  '.button[data-action="close-modal"]',
);

openModalBtns.forEach(function(item) {
  item.addEventListener('click', handleOpenModal);
});
closeModalBtn.addEventListener('click', handleCloseModalBtnClick);
modalBackdrop.addEventListener('click', handleModalBackdropClick);

function handleOpenModal(evt) {
  evt.preventDefault();

  page.classList.add('show-modal');
  window.addEventListener('keydown', handleModalEscPress);
}

function handleModalBackdropClick(evt) {
  const target = evt.target;
  const nodeName = target.nodeName;

  const parent = this.closest('.modal-backdrop');

  if (nodeName !== 'DIV') return;

  handleCloseModal(nodeName);
}

function handleCloseModalBtnClick(evt) {
  evt.preventDefault();

  const target = evt.target;
  const nodeName = target.nodeName;

  handleCloseModal(nodeName);
}

function handleCloseModal() {
  // remove show-madal class from page
  page.classList.remove('show-modal');
  // remove event listener handleModalEscPress from window
  window.removeEventListener('keydown', handleModalEscPress);
}

function handleModalEscPress(evt) {
  // determine the code of the pressed button and
  const key = evt.code;
  // close madal if the escape key was pressed
  if (key !== 'Escape') return;

  handleCloseModal();
}
```

```css
.button {
  border: none;
  background: orange;
  cursor: pointer;

  &_actions {
    border-radius: 23.5px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    transition: background 0.2s linear;

    &:hover {
      background-color: #ff8b24;
    }

    &::before {
      display: block;
      width: 24px;
      height: 24px;

      @include bg-image('../images/products/cart-icon.png');

      content: '';
    }
  }
}

.page__content {
  font-family: $main-font-stack;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;

  color: $white-color;
}

.page__products {
  padding-top: 70px;
  padding-bottom: 70px;

  @media (min-width: 900px) {
    padding-top: 156px;
    padding-bottom: 156px;
  }
}

.page.show-modal .page__modal-backdrop {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 999;

  // display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;

  transition: opacity 300ms ease-in;
  pointer-events: auto;
  opacity: 1;
}

.page.show-modal .modal-backdrop__modal {
  display: block;
  // transform: translateX(0);
}


.container {
  max-width: 1110px;
  min-width: 320px;

  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;

  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;

  @media (min-width: 600px) {
    width: 550px;
    padding-right: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
  }

  @media (min-width: 900px) {
    width: 830px;
  }

  @media (min-width: 1107px) {
    width: 1110px;
  }

  // @media (min-width: 1200px) {
  //   width: 1068px;
  // }
}

.list {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.modal-backdrop {
  // display: none;

  background-color: rgb(24%, 20%, 20%, 1);

  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.modal-backdrop__modal {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;

  min-height: 100%;
}

.modal-backdrop__modal {
  position: absolute;
  // transform: translateX(470px);
  // transition: transform 900ms ease-in;
  display: none;
}

.modal__content {
  // width: 470px;

  max-width: 470px;
  width: 100%;

  background: white;
}

.modal__order-form {
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.order-form_back {
  margin-bottom: 35px;
}

.order-form-back__button {
  position: relative;

  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 84px;
  padding-bottom: 67px;

  background-color: $secondary-accent-color;
}

.order-form-back-button__text {
  display: inline-block;

  font-size: 60px;
  line-height: 1.2em;
  color: $white-color;
}

.order-form-back-button__icon {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 44px;

  display: inline-block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 30px;

  @include bg-image('../images/order/back-arrow-icon.png');

  @media (min-width: 370px) {
    left: 57px;
  }
}

.order-form__container {
  width: 320px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 15px;

  @media (min-width: 370px) {
    width: 348px;
    padding: 0;
  }
}

.order-form__products-list {
  margin-bottom: 60px;
}

.order-form__products-item {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 57px;

  &:last-child {
    margin-bottom: 0;
  }
}

.order-form__poduct {
  display: flex;

  &::after {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -26px;
    z-index: 999;

    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 1px;

    background: $light-gray-color;

    content: '';
  }
}

.order-form-product__content {
  font-family: 'Gilroy';
  font-weight: 300;
  font-style: normal;

  color: $darck-gray-color;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.order-form-product__image {
  margin-right: 32px;
}

.order-form-product__name,
.order-form__quantity,
.order-form__single-price {
  margin: 0;
}

.order-form-product__name {
  margin-bottom: 12px;

  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1.2em;

  @media (min-width: 470px) {
    font-size: 18px;
  }
}

.order-form__quantity {
  margin-bottom: 4px;

  font-size: 20px;

  @media (min-width: 470px) {
    font-size: 24px;
  }
}

.order-form__single-price {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 800;

  @media (min-width: 470px) {
    font-size: 24px;
  }
}

.order-form__subtotal {
  position: relative;

  margin-bottom: 45px;

  font-family: 'Gilroy';
  font-style: normal;

  color: $darck-gray-color;
  text-transform: uppercase;

  &::after {
    position: absolute;

    z-index: 999;

    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 1px;

    background: $light-gray-color;

    content: '';

    @media (min-width: 470px) {
      bottom: -26px;
      left: -60px;

      width: 470px;
    }
  }
}

.order-form__subtotal-text,
.order-form__subtotal-value {
  display: block;

  line-height: 1.2em;
  font-weight: 300;
}

.order-form__subtotal-text {
  font-size: 30px;

  @media (min-width: 470px) {
    font-size: 24px;
  }
}

.order-form__subtotal-value {
  font-size: 44px;

  @media (min-width: 470px) {
    font-size: 48px;
  }
}

.order-form__action {
  margin-bottom: 23px;
  text-align: center;
}

.order-form-action__button {
  padding: 25px 0;
  border-radius: 5px;

  background: $secondary-accent-color;
}

.order-form-action-button__text {
  margin: 0 55px;

  font-family: 'Gilroy';
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 1.2px;
  font-weight: 800;
  font-style: normal;

  color: $white-color;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
  <title>Fizzyslim</title>

</head>

<body class="page page__wrapper">
  <div class="page__container page__content">
    <main class="main-content page__maine-content">

      <!-- PRODUCTS SECTION -->
      <section class="products products__wrapper page__products">
        <div class="products__content products__container container">          
          <div class="product__actions product-actions">
            <form action="" class="product-actions__form product-actions__form-content">

              <button class="product-actions__button button button_actions" type="submit" data-cmd="add-to-cart" data-action="open-modal">
                <span class="visually-hidden">Add to cart</span>
              </button>
            </form>
          </div>
  </div>
  </section>

  </main>

  <!-- MODAL-BACKDROP -->
  <div class="modal-backdrop page__modal-backdrop">
    <div class="modal modal__content modal-backdrop__modal">
      <form class="order-form modal__order-form" action="">
        <div class="order-form_back order-form-back">
          <button class="order-form-back__button order-form-back-button button" type="submit" data-action="close-modal">
          <span class="order-form-back-button__icon">
            <img
              class="image"
              src="./images/order/back-arrow-icon.png"
              width="20"
              height="30"
              alt="Back arrow"
            />
          </span>
          <span class="order-form-back-button__text">Carello</span>
        </button>
        </div>

        <div class="order-form__container">
          <ul class="order-form__products-list list">
            <li class="order-form__products-item">
              <div class="order-form__poduct order-form-product order-form-product__content">
                <img class="order-form-product__image" src="./images/order/apple-preview.png" alt="Offerta fizzyslim con sapore di Apple" width="63" height="113" />

                <div class="order-form-product__descr">
                  <p class="order-form-product__name">
                    Offerta<br /> fizzyslim con sapore di<br /> Apple
                  </p>

                  <p class="order-form__quantity">QTÀ: 3</p>

                  <p class="order-form__single-price">€25.50</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </li>

            <li class="order-form__products-item">
              <div class="order-form__poduct order-form-product order-form-product__content">
                <img class="order-form-product__image" src="./images/order/berries-preview.png" alt="Offerta fizzyslim con sapore di Berries" width="63" height="113" />

                <div class="order-form-product__descr">
                  <p class="order-form-product__name">
                    Offerta<br /> fizzyslim con sapore di<br /> Berries
                  </p>

                  <p class="order-form__quantity">QTÀ: 3</p>

                  <p class="order-form__single-price">€25.50</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </li>

            <li class="order-form__products-item">
              <div class="order-form__poduct order-form-product order-form-product__content">
                <img class="order-form-product__image" src="./images/order/grapefruit-preview.png" alt="Offerta fizzyslim con sapore di Grapefruit" width="63" height="112" />

                <div class="order-form-product__descr">
                  <p class="order-form-product__name">
                    Offerta<br /> fizzyslim con sapore di<br /> Grapefruit
                  </p>

                  <p class="order-form__quantity">QTÀ: 3</p>

                  <p class="order-form__single-price">€25.50</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </li>
          </ul>

          <div class="order-form__subtotal">
            <span class="order-form__subtotal-text">Subtotale</span>
            <span class="order-form__subtotal-value">€455.00</span>
          </div>

          <div class="order-form__action order-form-action">
            <button class="order-form-action__button order-form-action-button button" type="submit">
            <span class="order-form-action-button__text"
              >Visualizza carrello</span
            >
          </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>


  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jQueryFormStyler/2.0.2/jquery.formstyler.min.js"></script>


  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Помогите, пожалуйста, поправить код js.
Необходимо, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку Добавить в корзину плавно выходила форма заказа.
Клик по кнопке back-arrow возвращает назад (кликабельным должен быть весь оранжевый блок). Клик по затемненной области аналогично - возвращает назад (скрывает корзину)

Только учу js поэтому реализовал этот функционал криво и без плавного выхода и исчезновения.

Ссылка на исходные [файлы на github](https://github.com/monsara/fizzyslim)

Comment: Код надо вставлять непосредственно в вопрос.

Comment: Добавил. Если необходимо, удалю лишнее.

Comment: Спасибо, хороший вопрос получился. Теперь желательно бы уточнить, что значит *плавно выходила форма заказа.*. Форма заказа должна выплывать сверху, увеличиваться, плавно меняться ее прозрачность. Какой эффект хотите?